# How to resolve "The following alternatives can never be matched"

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I have been struggling to resolve a "multiple alternatives" error in my parser for a couple of days now but with no success. I have been converting Bart Kiers excellent Tiny Language(TL) tutorial code to C# using Sam Harwell's port of ANTLR3 and VS2010. Kudos to both these guys for their excellent work. I believe I have followed Bart's tutorial accurately but as I am a newbie with ANTLR I can't be sure.

I did have the TL code working nicely on a pure math basis i.e. no "functions" or "if then else" or "while" (see screenshot of a little app)

[image: Simple Maths Parser based on Bart Kiers work]

but when I added the code for the missing pieces to complete the tutorial I get a parsing error  in "functionCall" and in "list" (see the code below)

```
grammar Paralex2;

options {
    language=CSharp3;
    TokenLabelType=CommonToken;
    output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
  BLOCK;
  RETURN;
  STATEMENTS;
  ASSIGNMENT;
  FUNC_CALL;
  EXP;
  EXP_LIST;
  ID_LIST;
  IF;
  TERNARY;
  U_SUB;
  NEGATE;
  FUNCTION;
  INDEXES;
  LIST;
  LOOKUP;
}

@lexer::namespace{Paralex2}
@parser::namespace{Paralex2}

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

@parser::header {using System; using System.Collections.Generic;}

@parser::members{

public SortedList<string, Function> functions = new SortedList<string, Function>();

  private void defineFunction(string id, Object idList, Object block) {

    // `idList` is possibly null! Create an empty tree in that case. 
    CommonTree idListTree = idList == null ? new CommonTree() : (CommonTree)idList;

    // `block` is never null.
    CommonTree blockTree = (CommonTree)block;

    // The function name with the number of parameters after it the unique key
    string key = id + idListTree.Children.Count();
    functions.Add(key, new Function(id, idListTree, blockTree));
  }

}

public parse
  :  block EOF -> block
  ;

block
  :  (statement | functionDecl)* (Return exp ';')?  -> ^(BLOCK ^(STATEMENTS statement*) ^(RETURN exp?))
  ;

statement
  :  assignment ';'   -> assignment
  |  functionCall ';' -> functionCall
  |  ifStatement
  |  forStatement
  |  whileStatement
  ;

assignment
  :  Identifier indexes? '=' exp 
     -> ^(ASSIGNMENT Identifier indexes? exp)
  ;

functionCall
  :  Identifier '(' expList? ')' -> ^(FUNC_CALL Identifier expList?)
  |  Assert '(' exp ')'    -> ^(FUNC_CALL Assert exp)
  |  Size '(' exp ')'      -> ^(FUNC_CALL Size exp)
  ;

ifStatement
  :  ifStat elseIfStat* elseStat? End -> ^(IF ifStat elseIfStat* elseStat?)
  ;

ifStat
  :  If exp Do block -> ^(EXP exp block)
  ;

elseIfStat
  :  Else If exp Do block -> ^(EXP exp block)
  ;

elseStat
  :  Else Do block -> ^(EXP block)
  ;

functionDecl
  :  Def Identifier '(' idList? ')' block End 
     {defineFunction($Identifier.text, $idList.tree, $block.tree);}
  ;

forStatement
  :  For Identifier '=' exp To exp Do block End 
     -> ^(For Identifier exp exp block)
  ;

whileStatement
  :  While exp Do block End -> ^(While exp block)
  ;

idList
  :  Identifier (',' Identifier)* -> ^(ID_LIST Identifier+)
  ;


expList
  :  exp (',' exp)* -> ^(EXP_LIST exp+)
  ;

exp 
  :  condExp  
  ;  

condExp  
  :  (orExp -> orExp)   
  |  ( '?' a=exp ':' b=exp -> ^(TERNARY orExp $a $b)
  |  In exp         -> ^(In orExp exp)
  )?  
  ;  

orExp  
  :  andExp ('||'^ andExp)*  
  ;  

andExp  
  :  equExp ('&&'^ equExp)*  
  ;  

equExp  
  :  relExp (('==' | '!=')^ relExp)*  
  ;  

relExp  
  :  addExp (('>=' | '<=' | '>' | '<')^ addExp)*  
  ;

addExp
  :  mulExp ((Add | Sub)^ mulExp)*
  ;

mulExp
  :  powExp ((Mul | Div)^ powExp)*
  ;

powExp  
  :  unaryExp ('^'^ unaryExp)*  
  ;

unaryExp
  :  Sub atom -> ^(U_SUB atom)
  | '!' atom -> ^(NEGATE atom)
  |  atom
  ;

atom
  :  Nmber
  |  Bool
  |  Null
  |  lookup
  ;

list
  :  '[' expList? ']' -> ^(LIST expList?)
  ;

lookup
  :  list indexes?              -> ^(LOOKUP list indexes?)
  |  functionCall indexes?      -> ^(LOOKUP functionCall indexes?)
  |  Identifier indexes?        -> ^(LOOKUP Identifier indexes?)
  |  String indexes?            -> ^(LOOKUP String indexes?)
  |  '(' exp ')' indexes?       -> ^(LOOKUP exp indexes?)
  ;

indexes
  :  ('[' exp ']')+ -> ^(INDEXES exp+)
  ;


/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

Assert      : 'assert';
Size        : 'size';
Def         : 'def';
If          : 'if';
Else        : 'else';
Return      : 'return';
For         : 'for';
While       : 'while';
To          : 'to';
Do          : 'do';
End         : 'end';
In          : 'in';
Null        : 'null';

Or          : '||';  
And         : '&&';  
Equals      : '==';  
NEquals     : '!=';  
GTEquals    : '>=';  
LTEquals    : '<=';  
Pow         : '^';  
GT          : '>';  
LT          : '<';
Add         : '+';
Sub         : '-';
Mul         : '*';
Div         : '/';
Modulus     : '%';
OBrace      : '{';
CBrace      : '}';
OBracket    : '[';
CBracket    : ']';
OParen      : '(';
CParen      : ')';
SColon      : ';';
Assign      : '=';
Comma       : ',';
QMark       : '?';
Colon       : ':';

Bool
    :   'true'
    |   'false'
    ;

Nmber
    : Int ('.' Digit*)?
    ;

Identifier
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | Digit)*
  ;

String
@after {
  setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length()-1).replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1"));
}
  :  '"'  (~('"' | '\\')  | '\\' ('\\' | '"'))* '"' 
  |  '\'' (~('\'' | '\\') | '\\' ('\\' | '\''))* '\''
  ;

Comment
  :  '//' ~('\r' | '\n')* {Skip();}
  |  '/*' .* '*/'         {Skip();}
  ;

 Space
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C') {Skip();}
  ;

fragment Int  
  :  '1'..'9' Digit*  
  |  '0'  
  ;  

fragment Digit   
  :  '0'..'9'  
  ;
```

The error messages I get are

Decision can match input such as "CParen" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 : Line 79:20

and

Decision can match input such as "CBracket" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2 : Line 176:10

The errors relate to the functionCall and list rules. I have examined the parser file in ANTLRWorks 1.5 and confirmed the same errors there. The syntax diagrams for the two rules look like this;

[image: functionCall rule showing parsing error]

and this;

[image: list rule showing parsing error]

I have tried several changes to try to solve the problem but I don't seem to be able to get the syntax right. I would appreciate any help you guys could provide and can email the images if that would help.

Thanks in advance
Ian Carson

Comment: I don't know what's in the images you tried to post, but it looks like your rules are slightly ambiguous, and that's where the problem comes from. For example, there is nothing to distinguish the `Identifier ( explist? ) ` case from the `Array ( exp ) ` case...

Comment: @Stobor Thanks for the pointer I'm sitting here looking at ANTLRWorks syntax diagrams (sadly for me I think their cool :-) ) and trying out a few things. No luck so far but the night is young!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an OR-operator too many in the `condExp` rule making the grammar ambiguous.

You have:

```
condExp  
  :  ( orExp               -> orExp)   
  |  ( '?' a=exp ':' b=exp -> ^(TERNARY orExp $a $b)
     |  In exp             -> ^(In orExp exp)
     )?  
  ;
```

corresponding to:

[image]

But it should be:

```
condExp  
  :  ( orExp               -> orExp)
     ( '?' a=exp ':' b=exp -> ^(TERNARY orExp $a $b)
     |  In exp             -> ^(In orExp exp)
     )?  
  ;
```

corresponding to:

[image]

Comment: Hi Bart, Many thanks for having a look at this little one for me. That's fixed it! I guess one of the many tricks that come with experience is to look beyond the immediate problem rule as the whole structure works as a system. I'll keep it in mind for the next time. I added the missing images to complete my question and I tried to up vote you but need 15 points - I'll come back later